# Running an AWS Lambda function Under Different IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm working on a Node.js project that happens to have an AWS lambda function. We'll call it `funcA`. It can `getObject()` and `putObject()` on a specific s3 bucket.

We have a Dev environment with Node.js running on an Elastic Beanstalk instance. The instance runs on an IAM role that is specifically for dev. This IAM role allows it to invoke the Lambda function and access the dev S3 bucket. Here's where it get's tricky...

We also need to have separate staging and production environments, which will also be on Elastic Beanstalk. Those environments also need to use this lambda functions. However, these are different EB instances running under different IAM roles. Those roles should only be able to access the staging bucket and production bucket, respectively.

I am told by our infrastructure team that this means that I have to have three separate environment-specific Lambda functions: so funcA_dev, funcA_staging, funcA_prod. It's literally the same exact code doing the same exact thing but because it will have a different role I have to have triplicate copies.

I understand that a Lambda has to have a role. However, it seems like a very sub-standard workflow. Is there a better way to manage this? The key criteria are to use IAM roles (no permanent or hard-coded keys), and to scope roles tightly so that if for example the dev credentials were somehow compromised it would not affect the production bucket and stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a lambda deployment for each environment is pretty common (and I would say the [standard way](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/stages-in-serverless-framework.html) of achieving what you want)- sure, they might be the same exact thing *now*, but you may need to add new functionality to the lambda that you'll only want to test in development &c.

As your project grows it's even common to end up with your dev/stage/prod environments in separate AWS accounts (especially given the account-wide limits AWS imposes- [discussion](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/account-management/aws-multi-account-security-strategy/)).

If you *really* want to avoid having three lambdas, your best route is to take on the duty of role assumption yourself. The mechanism lambda uses to get its temporary IAM role is STS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html). This means that you could pass your lambda different temporary credentials, which you could specify and allocate in the Elastic Beanstalk instance.

However I'd really urge you to have a copy of your lambda for all three environments.